# How to auto accept ssh keys for plink in python?

Tags: python, ssh, plink

```
term = subprocess.Popen("plink  admin@hostname  -pw 
           password",shell=False,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

> WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!
>   The server's host key does not match the one PuTTY has
>   cached in the registry. This means that either the
>   server administrator has changed the host key, or you
>   have actually connected to another computer pretending
>   to be the server.
>   The new dss key fingerprint is:
>   ssh-dss 512 bd:21:76:e8:ad:e4:99:18:e6:4d:fa:ca:27:cf:32:99
>   If you were expecting this change and trust the new key,
>   enter "y" to update PuTTY's cache and continue connecting.
>   If you want to carry on connecting but without updating
>   the cache, enter "n".
>   If you want to abandon the connection completely, press
>   Return to cancel. Pressing Return is the ONLY guaranteed
>   safe choice.
>   Update cached key? (y/n, Return cancels connection)

how can I overcome this?

I can not use `paramiko` as the server won't lep open session using `paramiko`. I have to do it with `plink`. I have many servers nearly 100 with 4 IP's each amounting to 400 IP's So I can not manually accept the keys

Comment: *"as the server won't lep open session using paramiko"* - Why?

Comment: when I use parmiko channel gets closed when I execute the command .

Comment: So what if ask a question about your problem with Paramiko rather that trying to hack it using Plink?

Comment: I tried a lot searching the solution but I never could find. So I gave up paramiko. plink is working for me except the keys issue

Comment: I do not think you have chosen wisely. But ok, then your question is duplicate.